# How to describe current job on CV

Tags: resume, software-industry, career-development

I took my current job because it gave me an excellent opportunity to work in another country. The job has been successful for lifestyle and personal growth reasons, but I am worried that it hasn't been terribly good for my professional development and career prospects.

I am a software developer with 6 years experience, mainly in Java and Java-related technologies. I have been in my current job for just over 2 years. Although it is technically a Java development position, I spend most of my time working in a proprietary XML-based development environment. I do a fair mix of analysis, design, new development, and defect fixing, but I feel like I am falling behind the state of the art in the software world, so am looking elsewhere.

My problem is I have got no idea how to describe this job in an attractive way. All the sample resumés that I read on the internet contain sections where they describe all their achievements in their jobs:
"Designed and implemented a new security module ..."
"Refactored the transaction processing module, resulting in 2x increase in performance..."
"Redesigned the landing page, resulting in 100 new signups..."

I really don't have anything similar that I can say about my current job. I like to think I'm a solid member of the team that develops features as requested and fixes bugs as they arise. How do I portray my current position in a way that is attractive to potential employers?

Comment: Is your current job in jeopardy that u feel that u should match up with current trends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest something along the lines of:

> Current Role: Java and XML-based proprietary language development
>
> Responsibilities include:
>
> - Analysis ...
> - Software design including ...
> - Development of new software projects such as ...
> - Support work including ...

It's not clear what the mix is from the resume, 50/50 or biased one way or the other, but it's a true statement, and includes enough positives to get you in to an interview. Following it up in an interview, be honest about the mix, but if you're already in an interview and

- are capable of talking about Java in a pretty up-to-date way;
- know what you're doing in a technical test;
- can talk positively about the transferrable skills - software lifecycle, design, Agile/Scrum/other methodologies, best practices etc.

Then the fact that you've largely been doing some proprietary XML work recently shouldn't count against you.

Comment: This is a great answer. Focus on the things you accomplish, not on the tools you use to accomplish them. Tools come and go, and can be learned quickly. I have found that those who identify themselves primary by the language they work in eventually hit a limit in their career growth.

Comment: Thanks, I found this to be a fantastic and encouraging answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe focus a little bit more on why you actually wanted the job. You did a great job in explaining it here, so why not use similar words for the employer?

Java is not everything. Especially in project management jobs or jobs where you have to get along with customers or other departments you need to have life experience and everything you get by travelling. Put the emphasis on the thing's that make you special. Not everyone worked abroad for 2 years!